# I want to show a virtual column that show the table name from which its relative datas are retrieved

Tags: mysql

```
select substances,[table_name(i.e annex2)] 
    from annex2 where substances like '%methyl%' 
    union  select substances,[table_name(i.e annex3)] from annex3 
    where substances like '%methyl%'
```

Like the code shown above, i want to add a column with a table name corresponding to its data.It's maybe a virtual column coz there isn't a column like this in any of my table structure. Could anyone help me to go through this?

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select the table name as a string literal. Note that since you now know for a fact that there won't be any duplicates between the results from the two tables (since you're selecting a different string literal), you can use `union all` instead of `union`, and probably speed up the query a bit:

```
SELECT substances, 'annex2' AS table_name
FROM   annex2
WHERE  substances LIKE '%methyl%'
UNION ALL
SELECT substances, 'annex3' AS table_name
FROM   annex3
WHERE  substances like '%methyl%'
```

Comment: how naive am i? Thank you.